# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Requests_Response::is_redirect() in class-requests.php on line 685

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem when i upgrade to wordpress 4.6 ( i am using the theme Rosie from free vision). My website is working in home page url and other urls. However i was not able to access my Admin page (http://www.kidswallpainting.com/wp-admin).

It gives the following error

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Requests_Response::is_redirect() in /home/content/83/10792583/html/riot/kidswallpainting/wp-includes/class-requests.php on line 685

Tried the following.

- Manually resting the plugins by renaming the plugins folder to
  Plugin.hold. But this did not worked.
- Tried downgrading the WordPress to 4.5 Version as per instruction. But still getting the same issue in the admin.

I contacted the support of Theme owners , however they want me to wait until the new version is released ( i failed to check the version support of Theme beforehand )

Can someone help me out this ?

Comment: These links might help: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-on-wp-46-update/, https://github.com/ServerPress/ds-cli/issues/3

Comment: Yes i have gone through that link before. But the solution prescribed there is not working for me.I do not use DC-CLI plugin in my theme and i have Manually reverted back to older versions of WordPress.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, website works fine, but access to the dashboard / wp-admin is just an empty page.

The problem in my case was that one or more of the plugins was using an outdated version of the https://github.com/rmccue/Requests library. Wordpress new version 4.6 adds this library to the default install, but it seems that older versions in the plugin folder are preferred. So what you need to do is to find the plugin and de-activate it, or update the requests library in all other places yourself.

If you have shell access to the wordpress install, you can run
'find . -iname requests' in your wordpress plugin directory. Look out for all folders that are named rmccue/Requests or similar. Then either move that plugin away to remove it, or update the requests library directly by getting a new version from the above github link.

In my case the culprit was the jekyll-export plugin.

Comment: Thanks! In my case it was the wpsolr-search-engine plugin

Comment: Thanks too, for one of my client's site it was the [Mediacore Chooser](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mediacore/) plugin. Replacing the library fixed the site

Comment: I had the same issue with the jekyll-export plugin.